# Suspending a Kotlin coroutine until a flow has a specific value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am currently playing around with Kotlin coroutines and flows. In my scenario, a `MutableStateFlow` represents a connection state (`CONNECTING, CONNECTED, CLOSING, CLOSED`). It is also possible to login, logout and login again.

For further use of the connection, I have to check the state and wait until it is `CONNECTED`. If it is already `CONNECTED`, I can continue. If not, I have to wait until the state reaches `CONNECTED`. The `connect()` call does return immediately, the result is propagated via a callback that updates the `MutableStateFlow`. My current idea is to do the following:

```
connect()

if (connectionState.value != State.CONNECTED) { // connectionState = MutableStateFlow(State.CLOSED)

    suspendCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
        scope.launch { // scope = MainScope()
            connectionState.collect {
                if (it == State.CONNECTED) {
                    continuation.resume(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// continue
```

As I am fairly new to the topic, I don't know if this is good practice and I was also not able to find a more suitable concept in the Kotlin documenation. Is there some better way of doing it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A while back I had the same question:

[image]

It is preferred to use `first()` to suspend till the predicate is matched.

```kotlin
if (connectionState.value != State.CONNECTED) {
    connectionState.first { it == State.CONNECTED }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need this `if` here? Shouldn't the latest value be replayed to `first` making it check the current value?

Comment: @Eyjafl I think it's a small optimization, as reading the value of `StateFlow` is cheaper than setting up a Flow collector, which would mean to suspend the current coroutine.